# ASP.Net display data on repeater control with proper design with sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a project which in one module is like comparing two or more products. It's working properly but not displaying the proper design (output).

Here I have one image which i want. [image]

and my output displaying like:
[image]

I have them displaying on repeater control.
Here I have also my code **.aspx file**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table style="border: 1px solid #0000FF; width: 500px" cellpadding="0">
            <tr style="background-color: #FF6600; color: #000000; font-size: large; font-weight: bold;">
                <td colspan="2">
                    Sector Name
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table style="border: 1px solid #0000FF; width: 500px" cellpadding="0">
            <tr style="color: #000000; font-size: large; font-weight: bold;">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <%# Eval("fieldname") %></span><b>&nbsp;:</b> <span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("fielddetails")%></span> <b>&nbsp;</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #FF6600; color: #000000; font-size: large; font-weight: bold;">
                <td colspan="2">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" select fieldname,fielddetails from finalcomparedata where compare_id= "+6+" ", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
```

Comment: You can use Gridview control .if you want to show output in tabular format

Comment: remove colspan="2"
from this line 
<td colspan="2"><%# Eval("fieldname") %></span><b>&nbsp;:</b> <span></td>
and also manage your span tag. you have a closing span tag but there is no opening span tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your Table tag in header template and Add Table Headings There. Your Rows will be added in ItemTemplate and close tour table tag in footer template..like shown below

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">

<HeaderTemplate>
     <table >
    <tr>
    <th>Sector Name</th>
            <th>Heading2</th>
            <th>Heading3</th>
    </tr>
</HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td >
            <%# Eval("SectorName") %>
        </td>
        <td >
            <%# Eval("Heading2") %>
        </td>
        <td >
            <%# Eval("Heading3") %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>

<FooterTemplate>
    </table>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```